# Why do some collection classes have an "empty" instance method additionally to the class method?

Tags: scala, collections, methods, language-design

Both exist for example here:

```
Map.empty[Int, Int]
Map(1 -> 41).empty

Set().empty
Set.empty
```

But here only the class methods are existing:

```
List.empty        //OK
List(1,2,3).empty //Doesn't exist

Array.empty       //OK
Array("a").empty  //Doesn't exist
```

Isn't `empty` a perfect case for a class method (and shouldn't the instance method `empty` be deprecated therefore)?

Or should the an `empty` instance method be added to classes missing it?

Is there anything from a language point of view which makes it difficult only having `empty` as a class method (e. g. type inference, higher-kinded types, ...).

PS: 
It was suggested that Maps with default values would be harder to achieve without an instance method `empty`:

```
Map[Int, Int](1->2, 21->42).withDefault(_*2).empty
```

What do you think?

Comment: I guess the `empty` method on instances is an artifact from the pre-canBuildFrom-era.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's true, `empty` could be a method on the class instance. A reason why it's required by  sets and maps is because they implement their builders using this method. I guess a reason why it wasn't included elsewhere is because it wasn't a typical use case.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why does `Map` have `empty`, not the other way around. After all, it isn't an operation you do to something, it is just an instance of something.

Anyway:

```
(List(1, 2, 3): Traversable[Int]).companion.empty
```

I put in `Traversable` there just to show this works for any collection.

Answer (score 0):

there is only the immutable List. There is only one instance of an EmptyList, therefore a class level empty doesn't make sense.

The Map trait can be implemented by mutables, therefore you need multiple instances.

... I think there is something missing with this explanation, but maybe it is a start.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? There is no requirement that `List.empty` returns new instances. Why shouldn't it be possible to return `Nil` from List.empty?